# jqgrid is not reloading after saveRow succeded

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to add a new row to the my jqgrid, allow the user to inline-edit, save it by clicking on a 'save' button, and then automatically reload the grid with the added data.

My problem is with the reloading part of the process:

the jqgrid decleration:

```
jQuery("#gridMsg").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Content("~\\MessagesAndDeliveryInfo\\GetMessageAndDeliveryForDecisionImplementation\\")' + '?decisionImplementationId=' + '@Model.DecisionImplementationId',
        datatype: "json",
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        mytype: "GET",
        editurl: '@Url.Content("~\\MessagesAndDeliveryInfo\\SaveExistingMessage\\")',
        colNames: ['Msg No.', 'Date', 'Delivery Mode', 'Delivery Number', 'Confirmation Mode', 'Confirmation Date', 'IsVoucherCreated', 'Id'],
        colModel: [
                { name: 'MessageNumber', index: 'MessageNumber', width: 90 },
                { name: 'ProjectionDate', index: 'ProjectionDate', width: 90 },
                { name: 'DeliveryMode', index: 'DeliveryMode', width: 140, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: '@Model.DeliveryModeSelectOptions' }, formatter: showTextFmatter, unformat: unformatShowText },
                { name: 'DeliveryNumber', index: 'DeliveryNumber', width: 150, editable: true, edittype: "text" },
                { name: 'DeliveryConfirmationMode', index: 'DeliveryConfirmationMode', width: 110, align: "right", editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: '@Model.DeliveryConfirmationModeSelectOptions' }, formatter: showTextFmatter, unformat: unformatShowText },
                { name: 'LegalDeliveryDate', index: 'LegalDeliveryDate', width: 90, align: "right", editable: true },
                { name: 'IsVoucherCreated', index: 'IsVoucherCreated', width: 90, align: "right", editable: false, hidden: true },
                { name: 'IdForSendMailService', index: 'IdForSendMailService', width: 90, align: "right", editable: false, hidden: true },

            ],

        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#pagerMsg',
        direction: "rtl",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Messages",
        onSelectRow: function (id) {

            if (id && id != lastsel2) {
                jQuery('#gridMsg').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel2, function (response) { debugger; });
                jQuery('#gridMsg').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                lastsel2 = id;
            }
        },

        jsonReader: {

            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id",
            userdata: "userdata"
        },
        loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;
        }

    });
    jQuery("#gridMsg").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagerMsg', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
```

the add and edit row code:

```
     function AddRowToGrid()
{
    rowId = 99;
    var mydata = [
                    { MessageNumber: rowId, ProjectionDate: '@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()', DeliveryMode: '@Model.OPTIONS_DEFAULT_VALUE', DeliveryNumber: "", DeliveryConfirmationMode: '@Model.OPTIONS_DEFAULT_VALUE', LegalDeliveryDate: "", IsVoucherCreated: false, IdForSendMailService: null }
                 ]; 

    //add row
    for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
         jQuery("#gridMsg").jqGrid('addRowData', rowId, mydata[i]);


    //edit added row
    jQuery("#gridMsg").jqGrid('editRow', rowId,
    {
        keys: true,
        oneditfunc: function () {
                    //debugger;//alert("edited");
            }
    });

}
```

the saveRow code:

```
 function SaveNewRow(rowId)
{

        var saveparameters = {
            "successfunc": null,
            "url": '@Url.Content("~\\MessagesAndDeliveryInfo\\SaveNewMessage\\")',
            "extraparam": { decisionImpId: '@Model.DecisionImplementationId' },
            "aftersavefunc": reload,
            "errorfunc": function (rowId, result, postedData) { alert(result.responseText); restoreRow(rowId); },
            "afterrestorefunc": null,
            "restoreAfterError": true,
            "mtype": "POST"
        }

        jQuery("#gridMsg").jqGrid('saveRow',rowId,  saveparameters);
```

}

```
 function reload(rowid, result) {  $("#gridMsg").trigger("reloadGrid"); }
```

The above code works fine until reloading the grid: even though the new row was saved in the server and the aftersavefunc invoked: the grid is not reloading and the added row remains in editable mode.
Only when I manually click on reload grid in the navigation bar the grid is reloading and then I see the new row fine.

Hope someone can help me,
Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Don't you have an online page to check? Although couple of things look suspicious: why do you have parameters to your reload function? You call it without and it doesn't need any!

Comment: @MichaelLumbroso thanks. sorry, I don't have an online page. I found the reload fonction online somewhere, it has the parameters that are passed to the aftersavefunc, and it works fine. the reloadGrid is triggered but the grid is not actually beeing reloaded. Do you find anything else suspicious? If it helps, even when I just inline-edit an existing row and press enter to get to the editurl page, when it comes back successfuly the row is still in editable mode and not beeing reloaded.

Comment: I can't do much without an online page. Check the error console to see if there is information there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what causes the problem!

I have two editable columns in the colModel with edittype='select', those columns recieve the numeric code from the url, and use formatter and unformat (of colModel) in order to display the suitable text instead.

the formatting functions are:

```
 function showTextFmatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

    var vts = {};
    if (options.colModel.editoptions.values == undefined) {
        vtStr = options.colModel.editoptions.value.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < vtStr.length; i++) {
            kv = vtStr[i].split(':'); vts[kv[0]] = vtStr[i];
        }
        options.colModel.editoptions.values = vts;
    }

    if (options.colModel.editoptions.values[cellvalue] != "" && options.colModel.editoptions.values[cellvalue] != undefined)
        return options.colModel.editoptions.values[cellvalue].split(':')[1];
    return cellvalue;
}

function unformatShowText(cellvalue, options) {

    return cellvalue.split(':')[0]; 
}
```

the problem was in the first function: after editing the row and choosing an option from the select, the text was passed to the showTextFmatter function as the cellValue input instead of the numberic value, and an error has been thrown in line:

```
return options.colModel.editoptions.values[cellvalue].split(':')[1];
```

this error caused the reloading\restoring failure!

I just added a condition before the problematic line:

```
&& options.colModel.editoptions.values[cellvalue] != undefined
```

and the problem was solved.